# SqlServer Xml Data Type - How to Force Full End Elements

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml

I have a table in SQL Server...

```
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[LastName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[DataItemsXml] [xml] NULL,
```

which has an xml column. I want to store the xml in this column in the following format...

```
<data>
    <item-1>Some Data Here</item-1>
    <item-2></item-2>
</data>
```

Notice the empty element item-2. I need to store this in this manner to support some code I cannot modify.

Even when I pass the XML in the insert or update statement in this format, SQL Server appears to convert empty elements like item-2 to the following...

```
<data>
    <item-1>Some Data Here</item-1>
    <item-2 />
</data>
```

I understand that this is perfectly valid XML, but I need to have SQL Server store it in the first format, with full end tags for elements, even for empty elements.

I cannot figure out how to do this.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510442.aspx):

> SQL Server preserves the content of the XML instance, but does not
>   preserve aspects of the XML instance that are not considered to be
>   significant in the XML data model. This means that a retrieved XML
>   instance might not be identical to the instance that was stored in the
>   server, but will contain the same information.

I can't find any options that force SQL Server to expand elements as you wish.

If all you need is to *store* the XML rather than querying it, you *could* store it as a `varchar(max)` field, which would avoid the reparsing.  Alternatively, if it needs to be an actual `xml` field, you could convert it to text when retrieving it, converting the compact representation to end-element form using string manipulation.  Although it's probably theoretically possible to do such string manipulation in SQL Server, it's a much better idea to do it in a CLR procedure or in your application if you can.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that was the case. I do query on the data, so I will have to handle things differently in my code.